# r: scraping javascript web wage

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, nodes

I was trying to scrape web page and thus I used read_html command.
But I could not scrap the table that I want.
I think this page is with javascript. I don't know how to handle it.
Here is what I have done

```
  url=paste0("http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb-2006/results/#/page/2/")
site=read_html(url)%>%html_nodes('.tournamentTable')
```

or
     `site=read_html(url)
t<-html_nodes(site,"table")%>%html_table(fill=TRUE)`

but I got `{xml_nodeset (0)}`.
What is the wrong with my code? or this web site needs to use other command??

And I have tried `read_html(url)%>%html_nodes("table")` as well. But the tables form this command were the other side tables in the web page. It could not scrape the main table.

Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 0):

We are using the html_nodes() function to select the  nodes.

First we read the web page as:

```
webpage <- read_html("http://www.test.com/One.htm")
tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")
```

Refer the following link for reference:
http://bradleyboehmke.github.io/2015/12/scraping-html-tables.html

Mark answer as answered if it satisfies your requirement.

Comment: I've tried `html_nodes(url, "table")`  before, but it did not provide me the table that I want to scape